# How to set up network connection for Qemu on Windows Host? (TAP)

Tags: networking, qemu, u-boot

I am running u-boot for x86_64 on Windows machine. I installed Tap Network Adapter V9 from https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/ and created a link on my computer called tap0.
I checked network devices with "**ipconfig / all**" command in Windows and I can see tap0.

> Unknown adapter tap0:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
>
> Physical Address. . . . . . . . .   : 00-FF-E9-C4-2E-95
>
> DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1(Preferred)
>
> Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>
> Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
>
> NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

I run Qemu with tap support as below.

```
qemu-system-x86_64.exe -bios u-boot.rom -nographic -device  e1000,netdev=mynet0 -netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap0
```

tap: Could not open 'tap0'

qemu-system-x86_64.exe: Device 'tap' could not be initialized

How can I make network between Host and Guest for qemu in Windows?

Comment: A few months too late, but I just tried your command (with a little difference, that I booted from Debian 10 cd and did not use `boot.rom`) on my PC and it worked fine without giving any errors. There were no errors about tap0.